# What does it mean to say that a pom is installed in local repository?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

From the book [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps) inside the section *3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies* it says :

> If you create this project in a directory named persistence-deps, all
>   you need to do is create this pom.xml and run mvn install. Since the
>   packaging type is pom, this POM is installed in your local repository.
>   You can now add this project as a dependency and all of its
>   dependencies will be added as transitive dependencies to your project.
>   When you declare a dependency on this persistence-deps project, don’t
>   forget to specify the dependency type as pom.

What does it mean to say that a *pom is installed* in local repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time Maven needs to find a a dependency, it first looks in the local repository  - commonly located in an `.m2` directory in your user home. If it can't find the dependency there, it downloads the dependency into your local repository and uses it from there.

When it says a *pom is installed in the local repository*, it means the POM file was copied into the correct place in the local repository. Other projects you build locally can then resolve that dependency and use it.